# mongoimport from CSV file not assigning object ID's properly

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, mongoimport

I successfully followed commands to import from csv file to mongodb using CLI.

```
mongoimport --host myhost --ssl --username my_username --password my_password --authenticationDatabase admin --db my_db --collection addresses  --type csv --fields Geocords,Display_lat,Display_lng,street_address,added_by_user  --file exportdir2/MFCustomerList.csv
```

Now the object ID field is not something I have in my file. I expected each row to get its own object ID created on its own as I upload. However instead of just having an object id in there as so: **id_:"kalaklakp"**, each row has something like this in there: **id_:ObjectId("gaafagafagafs")**

This is causing major problems especially for my Parse instance , It is not able to identify these objects as valid.

Comment: Do you have object Id in csv or you want one of your fields to be _id? Can you add one sample value for that field?

Comment: I do not. I was expecting mongodb to create them. I would not know how to generate unique ones. So you suggesting I create a column for that the first row I submit something in there?

Comment: No, MongoDB creates automatically. That's what you see as `objectId`

Comment: So how can I get it to create it the way I’m used to it? The way Parse has it?